# How to Show Author image and url in WordPress plugin directory?

Tags: wordpress

I just added a plugin(My-auction-creator) in to WordPress Plugin directory. But sadly when I open the plugin URL the author image is not showing nor the url is linked.

So anyone can help me to show my image and url there?
Below the screenshot:
[image: See the screenshot here]
Here is the link:
[my-auction-creator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-auction-creator/)
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your username in `wordpress.org` profile ?

Comment: It's Suyog Computech Pvt Ltd. @Rohil_PHPBeginner

Comment: do you have gravatar account, To show your image wordpress needs it.

Comment: Yes I have @Mayur . And already given image there.

Comment: Are you sure ?? I am talkin about the UserName not Display name ..

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Sorry...Its Suyog Computech .

Comment: You should put your username in to your readme file so it will show up there with link. Currently it is not even having a link so My guess is that you have entered wrong username. [See Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-hide-success-message/) my plugin. You can see there is link.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Thanks man. Will change it . Be in touch :)